# Submit form to multiple url through jquery script

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, forms, spring

In my current spring project, I have a form with two types of fields: normal text fields and a file input to allow upload o image files. I want submit each one of this types of fields to a different method in my spring controller. The text fields should be submitted to one of this methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="insert", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String insert(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object)) {
        return "yes";
    }
    else {
        return "not";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String update(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.altera(object)) {
        return "yes";
    }
    else {
        return "not";
    }
}
```

the filem upload field should be submitted to this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String setPicture(@ModelAttribute(value="object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if(serv.upload_picture(object, file))
        return "pic-yes";
    else
        return "pic-not";
}
```

I have tried this jquery script so far, but it's working only with the text fields:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),  url = $form.attr( "action" );
    var posting = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        var alert = $("#"+data); 
        alert.css("display", "block");
        $(".form").each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
        $(".upload").each(function(){
            var $upload = $(this), url = $upload.attr("action");
            var posting2 = $.post( url, $(this).serialize() );
            posting2.done(function(data){
                $("#"+data).css("display", "block");
                $("#"+data).fadeOut(2500);
            });
        });
        alert.fadeOut(2500);
    });
});
```

the html code for the form currently it's like this:

```
<form id="command" role="form" class="form" action="Usuario/cadastra" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
      <p>
      <label for="login" class="form-control">login</label>
      <input id="login" name="login" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="senha" class="form-control">senha</label>
      <input id="senha" name="senha" class="form-control" type="password" value=""/>
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="first_name" class="form-control">first_name</label>
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="last_name" class="form-control">last_name</label>
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email" class="form-control">email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
      </p>    
      </div>
  </div>


        <div class="panel panel-default include">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Selecione um arquivo de imagem para <i>foto do perfil</i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <form id="command" class="form upload" action="/loja/Usuario/upload" method="POST">
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Anyone can point a direction to accomplish this?

Comment: Create a third method that calls the original 2 with the relevant data. Splitting the post data on the client side just seems wrong (and hard to do with file upload);

Comment: @user574632 I try once with one method, with both the object and the uploaded file as parameter (`public String insert(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file",required=false) MultipartFile file)`), but in this case I don't get submit none of the data (always face an error `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request`

Comment: Not a spring user, but you should aim to fix that error, rather than built a javascript hack. As a start, you need to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form tag - that alone might fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Exception: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

Have you add this line to your spring xml or applicationContext file.

**<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>**

Also add **spring-webmvc jar** in your classpath.

Comment: I don't use any xml file in my project, only java classes. Do you know the equivalent to that line in java code?

Comment: @KleberMota try: `@Bean public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
resolver.setMaxUploadSize(sizeInBytes);
return resolver; }`

Comment: @JoaoEvangelista Besides this, I also have tried add this line: `jsp_dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 1024*1024*5, 1024*1024*5*5, 1024*1024));` to my  WebAppInitializer, but still got the same error when I redeploy the application.

Comment: @JoaoEvangelista Through the Network Analyzer from the Browser, I notice only the text input fields are sent to server, none of the file input fields are listed there. I expected all the fields should be here. I ever knew only fields with the atribute `name` are sent to server, which is what's happening here. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you added encrtype to your form? It's multipart/form-data